# MVC Global error handling: Application_Error not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I am attempting to implement global error handling in my MVC application.

I have some logic inside my `Application_Error` that redirects to an `ErrorController` but it's not working.

I have a break point inside my `Application_Error` method in the the `Global.aspx`.

When I force an exception the break point is not being hit. Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you tried running application in non-debug mode? CTR+F5

Comment: Is your method have the right signature? Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) and not Application_Error() ?

Comment: <customErrors mode="Off" /> is present in your web.config?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try this approach for testing:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var error = Server.GetLastError();
    Server.ClearError();
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    Response.Write(error ?? (object) "unknown");
    Response.End();
}
```

Web.config

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

- [Rich Custom Error Handling with ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479319.aspx)
- [How to: Handle Application-Level Errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3.aspx)

Comment: No! thats a poor idea. I want the global error handling, to log the error and present a friendly screen to the user.

Comment: Your links are not really relevant to my question.

Comment: @Dan, you have not get my point. Debugger just can't step into your Application_Error method. Use my code without debugger and you will see that it works. BTW, you beat off any desier to help you.

Comment: Sorry - its not my attention to offend, just thought your initial answer was not up to scratch\clear.

Comment: Actually the debugger **CAN** step into the Application_Error method.

Comment: Marked down because the debugger CAN step into Application_Error as suggested by @user181328

Answer (score 2):

I think a better way to handle this would be using the [HandleErrorAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute.aspx) to decorate your controller (perhaps a base controller).  This would give you the option to do logging or handle errors in different controllers with different errors by extending this attribute and modifying it to fit your needs, say by changing the view that gets rendered.  Using this attribute uses the standard filter processing in MVC and builds the page using views rather than writing directly to the response as you might do using Application_Error.

Comment: Using the HandleError attribute doesn't help with errors that happen outside controllers as far as I can tell (for example in RegisterRoutes in Global.asax.cs).

Comment: @Michael - true, it only applies to a controller or controller method since the framework only recognizes the attributes there.  In practice I don't find this to be a problem.  For me, the only code that runs outside of an action is done at start up.  I use ELMAH with a custom HandleError attribute anyway so both of my bases are covered.

Comment: @tvanfosson same for ajax calls, also. It goes straight to the global.asax application_error if you have it... after some research and testing, I've decided upon a three prong solution. 

A. custom attribute using RegisterGlobalFilters not decorated controllers

B. Updating web.config to turn custom error handling on

C. JavaScript that captures all messages, either using the model and a helper method or direct from the ajax status code and a redirect to the error page via javaScript whereby the model and the ajax funnel their error into

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you for sure what's wrong, but I can think of a couple of things to check... firstly, is VS breaking on the exception? If you are in the debugger this is the default I think. If it is just hit F5 until you get to your code with the breakpoint. Also, are you sure you don't handle the exception anywhere before it gets to `Application_Error`?

Another thing to check - `CustomErrors` mode in web.config, this is set to `Off`, right?

Comment: No don't handle it elsewhere, im just getting an ungraceful standard asp.net error page.